# Error while configuring KnpGaufretteBundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundler

I am trying to configure `KnpGaufretteBundle` with the help of [KnpLabs](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle)

But at the point of configuring Filesystems in `config.yaml` I got this error

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: adapters in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony2\src\Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\
DependencyInjection\KnpGaufretteExtension.php
line 50
```

I have tried a lot to solved it.
Can any know how to remove this error or how to configure KnpGaufretteBundle  Bundle in `symfony 2.3.5` ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version do you use? Please add that part of `config.yaml` with configuration you have for this bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely forgot to add your adapters to the bundle configuration. That's why you end up with the exception when the extension tries to setup the filesystems [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/KnpGaufretteExtension.php#L50) ($adapters is unedefined).

Please follow the documentation [Configuring the Adapters](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle#configuring-the-adapters)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply,
in my config.yml i write below code
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        foo:
            local:
                directory: /path/to/my/filesystem

## app/config/config.yml

knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        # ...
    filesystems:
        bar:
            adapter:    foo
            alias:      foo_filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all, i have made following changes and its start working...

knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        foo:
            local:
                directory:  /path/to/my/filesystem
                create:     true

## app/config/config.yml

knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        foo:
            safe_local:
                directory:  /path/to/my/filesystem
                create:     true